# Getting values out of array in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure what title i should give to this but im running into a problem that's doing my head in.

im working on a project that involves drawing on a map, the map has different rooms and each room has a different size. on selecting a new room the map should resize. i store all the sizes in a array that i make at the top of my jquery. It basicly does the rescaling when the page loads as well because you have to pick a room you wanna start in, this rescale works as it should so i duplicated that code to the function but it doesnt seem to wanna work in there.

the array i use to build the rooms:

```
var hal1 = { id: 1, x: '0', y: '0', width: '114', height: '81', hal: 'Brabanthal'};
var hal2 = { id: 2, x: '0', y: '0', width: '33', height: '60', hal: 'Kempenhal'};
var hal3 = { id: 3, x: '0', y: '0', width: '87', height: '66', hal: 'Langstraathal'};  
var hal4 = { id: 4, x: '0', y: '0', width: '42', height: '47', hal: 'Diezehal'};  
var hal5 = { id: 5, x: '0', y: '0', width: '72', height: '57', hal: 'Peelhal'};  

var hallen = [ hal1, hal2, hal3, hal4, hal5 ];
```

this is code i use to rescale on page load

```
var hal = getUrlVars()["hal"];
if(typeof(hal) === 'undefined') hal=1;

var items = $.grep(hallen, function(x) {
    return x.id == hal
})

$(document).ready( function() {
    $.map(items, function(itemhal) {
     halw = itemhal.width;
     halh = itemhal.height;
     $('#mapDrag').width((Math.round(gridStand)*halw)*2).height((Math.round(gridStand)*halh)*2);
    });
});
```

all the above code works perfectly, its just the next function it doesnt work in. people can pick a difrent room out of a dropdown menu when they click on it its sends the id of the room(item) and runs the function with it. it then loads all the new data into the div mapdrag and it should then recale to the size given in the array where it matches the id like it does on initial page load.

the function where its not working in:

```
function changeHal(item) {
    if (hal != $(item).attr('halNr')) {
        hal = $(item).attr('halNr');
        var halXhr = jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/hal.php",
            data: 'hal=' + hal,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var items = $.grep(hallen, function (x) {
                    return x.id == hal
                })
                $.map(items, function (itemhal) {
                    halw = itemhal.width;
                    halh = itemhal.height;
                    $('#mapDrag').width((Math.round(gridStand) * halw) * 2).height((Math.round(gridStand) * halh) * 2);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

got the feeling its something really simple to make it work but i just cant seem to get it to work.

here is a jsFiddle with the basics of what it does in it. as you can see on load it scales the div in the right size, but on selecting a different room in the drop down it does not resize it.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gujPK/

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `response` from the AJAX call - is that intentional? What is the response?

Comment: your jsfiddle fails with  `getUrlVars is not defined` can you please give code for it show we can try to help you :)

Comment: You're abusing [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) - [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is used to translate a value into another one. [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is what you should use here instead

Comment: fiddle somehow didnt save... let me adjust it.

Comment: @Holapress I thknk fiddle working correctly .. in jsfiddle demo you gave i can see div size changing on selecting different hal... (Notice scrollbar changes)